# BareOS delete old backup and free up space

Tags: bareos

BareOS - drive full. How do I delete (cancel with bconsole) old jobs?

In this case I want to completely remote job #11030 and free that disk space up. How?

When I use bconsole's `disable job=11030` is gives me "not found".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the safest way to delete backups in BareOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/747544/what-is-the-safest-way-to-delete-backups-in-bareos)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "No" it does not, not only is that topic about Bacula, but also the link to the script is dead...